# lua for windows

Tags: lua, scite

I'm trying to use "lua for windows" - SciTE
Simply example such as `Print("hello")`
I hit Alt + R (per tutorial instructions), everytime I do this I get:
"Unable to debug program!"
Anyone had this problem?

Comment: @ra170, if you save your demo program, ie foo.ls or foo.lua and you run it, do you get that error?

Comment: On a side note, it's `print`, not `Print`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me on XP 32-bit.

I launched SciTE, opened a new document, typed `print "hello, world."` into line 1. Alt-R then prompted me to save the file before continuing. After saving it as `foo.lua`, the debugger started and line 1 was the current line. Clicking the Step button (or Alt+C) printed on the debug console as expected, and the debugger exited because there was no more program.

I did this in Lua for Windows v5.1.4.23, which is no longer the most current version.

I assume you've already checked all of the usual "is it plugged in" questions... you installed it normally, you have logged off and on again or rebooted sometime since the install, `lua -v` says something sensible, etc.

```
C:\...>lua -v
Lua 5.1.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio

C:\...>>
```

Do try running the file manually by saving it to `hello.lua` and saying `lua hello.lua` to a command prompt.

Comment: it runs manually, it's just when I try to run it in the debugger it bombs.

Comment: Did you already have SciTE installed before Lua for Windows installed a copy? It is possible that some of the debugger configuration is unique to the copy that was installed by LfW.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to add the extension to the file manually because you cannot choose any type of extensions while you saving the file (kind of bug), this solved my problem.

foo.lua